# Cakephp 3 - The page isn’t redirecting properly

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using **Cakephp 3.x** in which I have created one method inside my `AppController` (**checkBrandAssigned**) in which I have checked my logic and redirecting to the other page as per my needs. Below is how method looks like.

**AppController.php**

```
public function checkBrandAssigned(){

                $this->loadModel('Users');

                $user_data = $this->Users->find()
                    ->select(['user_id'])                    
                    ->where([                    
                        'user_type' => SALES_REPRESENTETIVE,
                        'user_status' => STATUS_INACTIVE,
                        'user_id NOT IN (SELECT ub_user_id FROM fp_user_brand)'
                    ])
                    ->order([ 'user_modified_date'=>'DESC'])
                    ->first();


                if (!empty($user_data)) {

                 return $user_data->user_id;   
                } else {
                    return '';
                }

    }
```

And below is my full  snippet of **AppController.php** file.

```
<?php 


class AppController extends Controller {


    public function initialize() {
    parent::initialize();

    switch ($this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.user_type')):

        case COMPANY_ADMIN :

            $loginRedirectUrl = ['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboardCompanyAdmin'];

            break;

        default : $loginRedirectUrl = ['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboardSalesRep'];
            break;
        endswitch;       
   }



    public function checkBrandAssigned(){

                $this->loadModel('Users');

                $user_data = $this->Users->find()
                    ->select(['user_id'])                    
                    ->where([                    
                        'user_type' => SALES_REPRESENTETIVE,
                        'user_status' => STATUS_INACTIVE,
                        'user_id NOT IN (SELECT ub_user_id FROM fp_user_brand)'
                    ])
                    ->order([ 'user_modified_date'=>'DESC'])
                    ->first();


                if (!empty($user_data)) {

                 return $user_data->user_id;   
                } else {
                    return '';
                }

    }
}
```

As you can see above, I have used `checkBrandAssigned` method inside my `beforeFilter` and if my condition gets true, I am redirecting at, `$this->redirect(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'brandRetailerView','?'=>['repId'=>'6b12337d37870e4afb708a20f4f127af']]);`.

Below is how my **UsersController.php** file.

**UsersController.php**

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    public function initialize() {
        parent::initialize();
    }

    public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {    
        parent::beforeFilter($event);                
    }


    public function brandRetailerView() {
        die('inside my function');

    }

}
```

As you can see I have put `die('inside my function');` I am able to see this text, howerver, If I comment it, I am getting error saying...

> The page isn’t redirecting properly

I have also created blank `brand_retailer_view.ctp` file in my respective location. Below is screenshot of my error.

[image]

I have also used [Auth Component](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html). I want `brandRetailerView` and `checkBrandAssigned` methods to be used after login hence I have not added inside my `$this->Auth->allow` in **AppController.php** and **UsersController.php**. However, I tried to add `checkBrandAssigned` in `$this->Auth->allow`, but still its not working.

I have tried to use `return parent::beforeFilter($event);` in my `UsersController.php` but its not working as well.

I have not added anything extra inside my `.htaccess` file, hence I am not adding here.

Can someone help me why I am having this issue. Even if I use `die` its working but as soon as I comment it, I am getting above error.

Comment: Are all the $loginRedirectUrl correctly authorized too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I have solved with below code.

```
case COMPANY_ADMIN :

  if (!empty($checkSalesRepId)) {

    if($this->request->params['action'] != 'brandRetailerView'){
        $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'brandRetailerView','?'=>['repId'=>$checkSalesRepId]]);
    }                        
    else {
        $this->dashboardUrl = ['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboardSalesManager'];
    }

}
```

Here I am simply checking if the current action is not `brandRetailerView`. If so, I am redirecting to `brandRetailerView` page, else `dashboardSalesManager` page.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

the issue is not in the code, it's in the logic

the issue is because irrespective of the condition returned by checkBrandAssigned(), the redirect will be to users controller and before filtering the user controller the condition will be checked again and will again be redirected to the user controller.

it will become an infinite loop of redirection, in case of die() it is working because die() break the loop before the redirect happens.

to solve this remove the redirect check from beforeFillter and put somewhere else...

add this to enable cookies in AppController.

```
use Cake\Controller\Component\CookieComponent;
```

and update the condition as follows.

```
if (!isset($this->Cookie->read('checkedInLast30Secs'))) {
        $this->Cookie->write('checkedInLast30Secs',
            [
                'value' => true,
                'expires' => '+30 secs'
            ]
        );
        if (!empty($checkSalesRepId)) {
            $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'brandRetailerView', '?' => ['repId' => '6b12337d37870e4afb708a20f4f127af']]);

            //     $this->dashboardUrl = ['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'brandRetailerView'];
        } else {
            $this->dashboardUrl = ['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboardCompanyAdmin'];
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you are still in doubt feel free to comment, thanks

Comment: although this not an appropriate approach but still just because you asked, the problem can be solved by cookies. I am editing the answer for the reference code.

Comment: ohhk, incase you this answer turna out to be coorect dont forget to marki it correct for the others to benefit from it